# If he even has one, what is Dragon's devil fruit power?

Tags: one-piece

What is Dragon's devil fruit power?

In Loguetown, it became stormy out of nowhere when he showed up. Also, I think I remember Smoker saying something about it.

Answer (score 3):

The only accurate answer is we do not know.  There is no proof Monkey D. Dragon has a devil fruit or that he does not have one.

There are many theories attributing the lightning strike that saves Luffy from the gallows to Dragon and, therefore, lightning to his devil fruit.  They hypothesize that he could have the storm storm fruit or air air fruit.  These are all speculation, however.

Comment: Just wanted to comment and say that I can't wait to see Dragon actually throw down in the future. He has gotten next to no action through out the series.

Answer (score 0):

If he has one, I'd say it's either Kaze Kaze no Mi (Wind) or Topu Topu no Mi (Gust). Based on;

- In Logue town to save luffy and repelling smoker away ([Chapter 100](http://www.mangareader.net/one-piece/100/26)),
- In Goa Kingdom, to save the people from trash mountain in Goa Kingdom by opening a path ([Chapter 587](http://www.mangareader.net/one-piece/587/14))

Even though it's not really clear in the manga what Dragon did in Goa, but in Anime it is clear that it's a similar thing that he used on Smoker back in Logue town. [Video source here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJbBSvapoRU)

Comment: I always thought in Goa Kingdom it was one if Ivan's winks that opened a path..

Comment: @Gravinco I've edited my post. IMO, it's impossible if iva's wink could cause huge wind and put out the fire, and it's too hard to believe if it's a coincidence.. And if I put it together with the event in Logue town, there's only one man who exists in both of events when such wind happening.

Comment: As you said there is no way to be sure so it will always be an assumption until we know more

Comment: @Gravinco exactly.. i even said if he even has one..